# how to values transfer to another column with two query

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query. this query is calculated percentage for every product. I created a virtual column on this query this columns name is 'yüzde'. After that, i want to transfer yüzde columns to another column in another table with update query if product ids are same.
I think I need to write a stored procedure. How can I do that?

```
SELECT [ProductVariantId] , 
       count([ProductVariantId]) as bedensayısı,
       count([ProductVariantId]) * 100.0 / (SELECT Top 1  Count(*) as Total    
  FROM [Live_ADL].[dbo].[_INV_ProductCombinationAttributes] 
  Where Size LIKE '%[^0-9]%' and [StockQuantity]>0
  Group by [ProductVariantId]
  order by Total Desc) as yüzde
FROM [Live_ADL].[dbo].[_INV_ProductCombinationAttributes]
 Where Size LIKE '%[^0-9]%' and [StockQuantity]>0
group by [ProductVariantId]
order by yüzde desc
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't really need a SP, you can do it in-line, using CTE for instance, something along these lines:

```
; with tabyuzde as
(
SELECT [ProductVariantId] , 
       count([ProductVariantId]) as bedensayısı,
       count([ProductVariantId]) * 100.0 / (SELECT Top 1  Count(*) as Total    
  FROM [Live_ADL].[dbo].[_INV_ProductCombinationAttributes] 
  Where Size LIKE '%[^0-9]%' and [StockQuantity]>0
  Group by [ProductVariantId]
  order by Total Desc) as yüzde
FROM [Live_ADL].[dbo].[_INV_ProductCombinationAttributes]
 Where Size LIKE '%[^0-9]%' and [StockQuantity]>0
group by [ProductVariantId]
)

update x 
set othertablevalue=yüzde
from
othertable x
join tabyuzde t on x.ProductVariantId=t.ProductVariantId
```